# What performance testing tools would you recommend?

Tags: performance

I am looking for a performance testing tool to help with development regarding 
performance enhancing changes. What I need is to be able to make a series of changes and be able to see if the response time is heading down or not.

I have heard of, and experimented with JMeter, Gatling, Siege etc.

I am not interested in load testing the application at this point, more just a small average to see if the code is more efficient or not. When I talk about changes I am only referring to code relating changes, not hardware / enviroment

Also what I am interested in with this is the reporting that comes with it, I ideally want some simple graphs, tables etc to represent the data.

Any recommendations would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing would be more appropriate than using the built in Magento profiler. It will give you a load time, unskewed by latency/tcp overheads/jitter/userspace overheads.

If you want to measure the impact of code level changes, profiler is perfect.

You could make an exceptionally simple module to log the results, then produce a graph in whatever you liked (eg. Magento reporting tools, Excel etc.)

At a platform level, if you are using MageStack, it logs PHP render time as standard and produces graphs/tables/charts automatically. So might be worth looking in to. It's visible on the main dashboard in Kibana (kibana.magestack.com)

Eg.

[image: MageStack kibana dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for customer-perspective performance monitoring, I would suggest giving [shoppimon.com](http://www.shoppimon.com/) a spin. Its a monitoring tool which is super-easy to set up and among other things will give you some insight into how a production site is doing from the end-user's perspective. It may not be what you need as a development tool, but if you're optimizing a production site it can be useful to test how you're doing over time.

DISCLAIMER: I am the CTO at Shoppimon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. I used Jmeter to test load and performace of the Magento website. Jmeter is good validator tool and generate quit efficient analysis report. Jmeter is quit useful for small and medium business to test website load and performance and it is free from any license.
2. Magento provide tool for performance testing :
   http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-speed-test.html